# Which LEGO set is a gray vehicle frame from?

Tags: set-identification

I bought a bag of LEGO in 2020, there is a frame which I think belongs to a vehicle. I have tried to search for the gray bricks with holes of 14x1 , but I could not identify the set. I might make a mistake with the color. Can anyone can identify the set from the photo? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be set [75086](https://rebrickable.com/sets/75086-1/battle-droid-troop-carrier/) Battle Droid Troop Carrier.

[image: Battle Droid Troop Carrier]